# Library kotlin version is not compatible with my project kotlin version - how to omit an error

Tags: react-native

I would like to use this library: https://github.com/nguyenvanquan7826/React-Native-Smart-Config-Quan
but when I wanted to compile it I got an error:

`[stderr]  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher. [stderr]  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: [stderr]  project ':react-native-smartconfig-quan' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50`

So I changed kotlin version of my project to 1.3.50 and prebuild it again and got another error:

`android.kotlinVersion" needs to be at least version 1.6.10`

Is it possible to omit somehow the error without downgrading the react-native version which supports kotlin version 1.3.50?

Current react-native version:
`"react-native": "0.71.8"`,

I suppose that the author of this library: React-Native-Smart-Config-Quan has to update the kotlin version or build gradle plugin to at least 1.5.20 (here: https://github.com/nguyenvanquan7826/React-Native-Smart-Config-Quan/blob/b7dd1c00e8cf24b95496ed137e2fce570b86f9fb/android/build.gradle#L13)
and this is the only way to fix this error?

I tried to downgrade the kotlin version of my project to 1.3.50 but my project requires at least 1.6.10 kotlin version.